# Html code for a "full-page" applet (no javascript)?

Tags: java, html, css, applet

Good afternoon all,

I have a Java applet that I wish to embed on a website. I require that the applet be *full-sized*, i.e. it occupies 100% width and 100% height of the webpage.

There should be no scrollbars.

This is the code I currently have:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body style="background:red; width:100%; height:100%; padding:0; margin:0; border:0;">
    <applet code="HelloWorld.class" style="padding:0; margin:0; border:0; width:100%; height:100%;">
        Your browser does not support the <code>applet</code> tag.
    </applet> 
    <!-- the applet should cover the entire page, so even though the body is red, it should be covered by the applet -->
  </body>
</html>
```

For some reason, it doesn't work on FireFox and IE. In Chrome, the applet appears to be *taller* than the page itself and thus a vertical scrollbar is shown. How do we make the applet fill the exact size of the webpage, showing neither any horizontal scrollbars nor vertical scrollbars?

PS: if possible, a solution which works on a browser that has JavaScript disabled would be cool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way...

```
applet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Comment: You might want to test that on a slew of browsers.  Last time I checked it, there were very [mixed results](http://pscode.org/test/resize/) for sizing applets using percentage values.  It is safer to (deploy &) size an applet using JS, that type of stuff is what JS is good at.

Answer (score 6):

Use absolute position.  Don't specify height or width.

```
applet {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Comment: But that whole point is that I wanted the applet to be full-width and full-height..

Comment: @pacerier - that is why you specify bottom and right.  It works the way you want.