# Performance benefits of Java applets in full screen mode?

Tags: java, applet, awt, fullscreen

I have made games in Java before, and am now trying my hand at my first Applet. My plans are for my applet to resize to fit the window as the user resizes the window. I am wondering if it is possible to get performance gains from "page-flipping" in a Java Applet if the browser is put in full-screen mode (F11 for chrome)? I plan on advertising a bit the fact that the game can be played as if in "full screen" by hitting F11 in most browsers - so I expect it to get some use... I just want to know if it is possible to get some of the same performance benefits in an Applet that I could when a regular Java application enters full-screen mode.

I am guessing that it is impossible for a few reasons: I don't think the browser would be able to detect that an Applet within the page is in "full-screen" and pass along direct access to the monitor's hardware, and second... I don't imagine most browsers would choose to pass it along to an applet anyways.

Anyone know if browsers give any special controls to a page in full-screen situations?

On another note, is it possible beyond the context of a browser for an Applet to become full-screen?

Comment: *"I have made games in Java before, and am now trying my hand at my first Applet."*  Code it in a `JFrame` (`JWindow` ..whatever) and launch it free floating using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  The only real point of an applet is if it has to be an inherent part of a web page (i.e. embedded within it).  'Full screen mode' is the antithesis of 'embedded in a web page'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html code for a "full-page" applet (no javascript)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9985755/html-code-for-a-full-page-applet-no-javascript)